# Password Strength

Tags: cipher, anagram, password, movies

<sub>*An entry to [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1) - based on [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/936/).*</sub>

I am the password manager, helping others remember passwords.

I am the password manager, receiving many calls each day.

I am the password manager, and I am stuck.

My latest client, Jobert, has requested my assistance to remember his Stack Exchange password. Jobert is an avid xkcd reader, and his password is four words. He remembers the following information:

> The password is 4 words.
>   The password consists of only lowercase letters and spaces.
>   The note on his desk was supposed to help him remember the password.
>   The note on his desk now makes no sense to him.

I took a look at the note:

> tilspmb ftpmb pcz nsdwmoem
>
> qshwiwb nxtb ufwxwbf qkqh
>
> ouwqk qxxrk rhtmz ntxcznbpp
>
> lsii ydlvetzm ctrpdaua lmuka
>
> mfhwwk yuma nletr aoexs
>
> oltiak qxtellrt rpne vnvdytl
>
> mfgt tvzbervsc geaxieqm ouxb
>
> obvrkvs cpzk micams tjpobr
>
> xtvbv wwbhgma wrwt pwrvt
>
> csrmk mzjeg pzsvz tpnegm
>
> lffkaln elqkxuk sztugwzn zjg
>
> brmwqf qxxg afkvemb pjg
>
> rfgxi coiyws nwdyxue vemsaces
>
> qumwbb cxbxbp pribqewxfpt lprxf
>
> tdtt invsgt cdottl xbvpa
>
> jsftnhbig pmxvvwofx eqvuee cdqe
>
> prabttrabvva koexmjoe vxjogq sdnuk
>
> svsaxljoe cejup xrk yegq
>
> potqeq zrxcz tofwbfx gqpnecasm
>
> aklzovtl ofvvetb mgabv wpttnbxuz
>
> yibevx cxtddppc yfwptf npplby

I am struggling just as much as Jobert to comprehend this hodgepodge. I ask him if this is English, but he refuses to speak to me.

I also saw this list taped to the wall, but it seems like Jobert's personal business. This won't help.

> To do list
>     - Make sure key is fixed
>     - Buy birthday present for Yobert
>     - Go watch a V movie
>     - Use beautiful strong ciphers
>     - Repair furnace

I am in a predicament.
  **What could Jobert's password possibly be?**

Hint 1:

The next day, I came back to Jobert's house to find new additions to his to do list.

> ...
>   - Send my first letter to the movie theater
>   - Get discord bot up and running
>   - Book tickets for Venom

Hint 2:

It's been a whole day and I haven't figured out the password. I asked Jobert if he remembered anything else, and he said

> Not all of the items on the list are useful.

He then showed me this:

> To do list
>   - Make sure key is fixed
>   -  <strike>Buy birthday present for Yobert</strike> 
>   - Go watch a V movie
>   - Use beautiful strong ciphers
>   -  <strike>Repair furnace</strike> 
>   - Send my first letter to the movie theater
>   -  <strike>Get discord bot up and running</strike> 
>   - Book tickets for Venom

Hint 3 (Basically gives away the answer):

I overheard Jobert on the phone.

> -Start Conversation-
>  ???: Why do we have to go watch Venom? That movie's gonna suck!
>  Jobert: But I have to, it's a V movie!
>  ???: What does that even mean?
>  Jobert: I don't care what you say, I'll go myself.
>  -End Conversation-

Comment: This is my first puzzle, so feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: I hope Jobert, an avid xkcd reader, is smart enough not to use a certain 4-word password.

Comment: Can I confirm that "Yobert" is intentional?

Comment: It's completely irrelevant, I just like names that rhyme with Robert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From neodne

> "Use beautiful strong ciphers" and "Make sure key is fixed" indicate using the Beaufort cipher with a key of "fixed." Applying this to the cipher text yields a plain text of four-word passwords:
>
> mammoth sloth ice squirrel = Ice Age
> olympic sled jamaica snow = Cool Runnings
> robot plant obese spaceship = Wall-E
> snap gauntlet genocide stone = Avengers: Infinity War
> rabbit hole queen dream = Alice in Wonderland
> puppet pleasure nose cricket = Pinocchio
> race lightning radiator road = Cars
> penguin gift tavern popper = Mr. Popper's Penguins
> alien bicycle home phone = E.T.
> clown sewer penny losers = It
> sadness emotion memories joy = Inside Out
> cowboy play daycare toy = Toy Story
> macaw brazil smuggle carnival = Rio
> police gadget investigate tools = Inspector Gadget
> lamp prince carpet genie = Aladdin
> underwear principal toilet cape = Captain Underpants
> independence treasure church mason = National Treasure
> miniature vault ant hero = Ant-Man
> orphan grace musical roosevelt = Annie
> internet pancake wreck milkshake = Ralph Breaks the Internet (corrected)
> hawaii galactic family stitch = Lilo & Stitch
>
> Each clues a movie, as indicated above.

With that, we

> solve the anagram created from the first letters of each movie title

to get

> Captain America Civil War

Comment: To solve this, I actually started with the link that David Starkey posted, noticed a lot of results had pncgnva and nzrevpn and completed the anagram from there. So it is a team effort and as such I think either this answer or neodne's should be made a community wiki and updated to include the whole shebang. But I don't want to be so presumptuous, so I'll see how the others weigh in. (Assuming this is correct, of course)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm not sure how community wikis work though, so I'll need some help on that.

Comment: If @neodne gives his permission, I'll copy his work (corrected) to this post and flag it community wiki. I think that is how it works, but I'm not 100% sure myself. My real concern is getting permission from neodne to use his work in this post for completeness.

Answer (score 8):

### Partial

> "Use beautiful strong ciphers" and "Make sure key is fixed" indicate using the Beaufort cipher with a key of "fixed." Applying this to the cipher text yields a plain text of four-word passwords:
>
> mammoth sloth ice squirrel = Ice Age
> olympic sled jamaica snow = Cool Runnings
> robot plant obese spaceship = Wall-E
> snap gauntlet genocide stone = Avengers: Infinity War
> rabbit hole queen dream = Alice in Wonderland
> puppet pleasure nose cricket = Pinocchio
> race lightning radiator road = Cars
> penguin gift tavern popper = Mr. Popper's Penguins
> alien bicycle home phone = E.T.
> clown sewer penny losers = It
> sadness emotion memories joy = Inside Out
> cowboy play daycare toy = Toy Story
> macaw brazil smuggle carnival = Rio
> police gadget investigate tools = Inspector Gadget
> lamp prince carpet genie = Aladdin
> underwear principal toilet cape = Captain Underpants
> independence treasure church mason = National Treasure
> miniature vault ant hero = Ant-Man
> orphan grace musical roosevelt = Annie
> internet pancake wreck milkshake = Wreck-It Ralph
> hawaii galactic family stitch = Lilo & Stitch
>
> Each clues a movie, as indicated above.

Comment: I sort of got lazy near the end, adding words like "popper" and "stitch" :3

Comment: Still a clever play on names :)

Comment: I managed to undecipher the words and my first thought was 'where is man door hand hook car door?'

Comment: Taking the hint 2 "first letter" bit, I'm guessing next is taking the first letter of all your answers.  After that, use the "Go see a V movie" and add a V to the letters.  Then [find a 4 word anagram of those letters](https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=icwaapcmeiitriacnaawlv&language=english&t=500&d=4&include=&exclude=&n=&m=&a=y&l=n&q=n&k=0).  None of them particularly stick out to me, though.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Well, I never said the titles are all correct...